# Get group by ID and associated user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a current_user which `has_many` groups. I have the `current_user.id` and a `params[:group_id']`.

I can't figure out how to Query it though. I get errors of the user id not existing.

I've tried:

```
@singleGroup = Group.where(:user => {id: current_user.id}).find(params[:group_id])
```

and

```
@singleGroup = Group.where(id: current_user.id).find(params[:group_id])
```

But they both don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it directly from current user

```
current_user.groups.where(:id => params[:group_id]).first
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Group.where(user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:group_id]).first
```

Answer (score 1):

```
current_user.groups.find(params[:group_id])
```